# Node JS database callbacks

Tags: node.js

Pretty much all of the stuff I have seen related to data queries under nodejs are writing to the console rather than returning the complete data from the function.

I am struggling to retrieve the queried data, here's what I have now but it returns nothing:

```
function dbGet(req,res,cb){
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('/usr/share/csServ/csdb.sqlite');
    var json = []; var jrow = {};
    db.each("SELECT * from sensors", function(err,row) { jrow['id'] = row.id; jrow['tstamp'] = row.tstamp; json.push(jrow);}, cb(json) );
}

dbGet(req,res,function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

How can I get the data into my callback and how can I close the db db.close() in the dbGet() function as I don't know when the each loop is completed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `cb(json)` as the `complete` callback, you'll need to wrap it in another `function` so it can wait to be evaluated:

```
db.each("SELECT * from sensors",
    function (err, row) { /* ... */ },
    function () { cb(json); }
);
```

As is, `cb(json)` is being called immediately, when `json.length === 0`, and its `return` value (currently `undefined`) is being passed to `db.each()`.

You can also use this same `function` to close the connection:

```
db.each("SELECT * from sensors",
    function (err, row) { /* ... */ },
    function () {
        db.close();
        cb(json);
    }
);
```